# WebDriver finding elements in grid layout

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jbehave

To test my application I use Selenium, JBehave and JUnit. To find elements in page I use WebDriver.

I have grid layout and in each part of grid I have button I want to click button like:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.className("v-button")).click();
```

but I want to click button from specific part of grid layout:

```
<div class="v-gridlayout-slot" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <div class="v-verticallayout v-layout v-vertical v-widget">
    <div class="v-slot">
    <div class="v-slot v-slot-h2">
    <div class="v-slot">
    <div class="v-slot v-align-right v-align-bottom">
      <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="v-button v-widget">
<div class="v-gridlayout-slot" style="left: 308px; top: 0px;">
```

I have structure like that in page and I want to click button from left top corner (with `style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"`).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You better ask a frontend developer to give ids to your buttons. Then search by specific id like 'btn-top-left', because this element will be unique on your page.
Searching elements by attributes is a bad practice, but if there is no other choise try really searching by attribute:
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'v-') and contains(@style,'left: 0px; top: 0px;')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath that searches for the parent div with a style attribute that 'contains' "left: 0px; top: 0px;". Alternatively, get all the divs with the class 'v-gridlayout-slot' and then check their style attribute via a string match until you find the desired element.